# Compare array by key with another array and add a line if doesn´t exist Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, compare

I have this array

```
[
    {name: 'Management Fees', amount: 3862.45, year: 2022, month: 8, date: '2022-08-02'}
    {name: 'Management Fees', amount: 4393.35, year: 2022, month: 9, date: '2022-09-06'}
    {name: 'Management Fees', amount: 5011.91, year: 2022, month: 7, date: '2022-07-04'}
    {name: 'Postage and Delivery', amount: 110.4, year: 2022, month: 9, date: '2022-09-01'}
    {name: 'Postage and Delivery', amount: 83.91, year: 2022, month: 7, date: '2022-07-26'}
]
```

I want to compare it with another array like this:

```
[7, 8, 9]
```

As you can see "Postage and delivery" doesn´t have month: 8 so in that case I want to add a new line in the first array with month: 8

Expected output:

```
[
    {name: 'Management Fees', amount: 3862.45, year: 2022, month: 8, date: '2022-08-02'}
    {name: 'Management Fees', amount: 4393.35, year: 2022, month: 9, date: '2022-09-06'}
    {name: 'Management Fees', amount: 5011.91, year: 2022, month: 7, date: '2022-07-04'}
    {name: 'Postage and Delivery', amount: 110.4, year: 2022, month: 9, date: '2022-09-01'}
    {name: 'Postage and Delivery', amount: 83.91, year: 2022, month: 7, date: '2022-07-26'}
    {name: 'Postage and Delivery', amount: 0, year: 2022, month: 8, date: '2022-07-26'}
]
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? I am guessing you take a value from second array then check against month value against first array? Then if you could not find one you add a record? And that has to be unique by name property of the first array items?

I would suggest you go through ES6 array functions, then you will have some ideas of what you want to use. You can chain them together. If I may suggest, I would say start with .find()

Comment: the problem is that i get the info from a service but the service doesn´t brings me anything when a month is not present. I want to pass this array to a table with months but if an object doesnt exist then the results wouln not be properly.

Comment: thats why I get the unique months of the first array and then i want to compare if all the names have all the unique months included

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.